# Clickable row with datatables

Tags: jquery, html

How do I go with making a `tr` clickable while using [**datatables**](http://datatables.net), though yet keeping the original browser's menu so they can middle-click for new tab or rightclick for the original browsers menu? (such as open in new tab, page, copy link, etc.) ?

I've tried [**Superlink**](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/table-rows-as-clickable-anchors/), but this does not work in all browsers, I need it to be cross-browser (IE7 and newer!)

Any tips/tricks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

check this example from **DataTables**: [**select_row**](http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/api/select_row.html) and see if helps you.

see the source `Initialisation code`

Answer (score 0):

This works!

```
oTable = $('#RectifiedCount').dataTable( ....);

 $('#RectifiedCount tbody tr').live('click', function (event) {        
    var aData = oTable.fnGetData(this); // get datarow
    if (null != aData)  // null if we clicked on title row
    {
        //now aData[0] - 1st column(count_id), aData[1] -2nd, etc. 
        alert("equis");
    }
});
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me...  Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'live'